# How can I replace Italian Residence Permit Card?

Tags: italy, lost-documents, ghanaian-citizens

I am a Ghanaian, currently in India for study, but have lost my Italian residence permit card. I asked a friend what to do, and was told to report the loss to the police with a photocopy of the permit, which I don't have. I do have my Italian school results; could that be of any help?

Comment: Were you issued a long-term residence permit, or short term while you were studying in Italy? How long ago did you leave Italy?

Comment: Have a look at this [article](http://permessodisoggiorno.org/come-tornare-in-italia-se-ti-rubano-o-perdi-il-permesso-di-soggiorno-allestero/) - according to what is written there you should apply for a visa again!

Answer (score 2):

Your question suggests that you were in the country as a student, and your residence permit would have been associated with that visa status. The validity of your residence card would have been the same as was indicated on your visa. As a non-EU national, you cannot simply replace the residence card, and cannot do so when you are no longer in Italy. Should you still have a valid Italian visa and plan to return to Italy and remain for more than three months, [you can apply](http://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10617), as you did previously, at your local Questura.

Comment: Hi Dorothy, your link seems to be broken! :)

Comment: @Hatef mille grazie